# Apache Spark freezed on YARN

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a standalone cluster (a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04) with Apache Spark 1.6 and Hadoop 2.6.4 installed using default configuration. Everything works fine when I run this:

`spark-submit --class org.broadinstitute.hellbender.Main --master yarn --deploy-mode client /home/hadoop/spark.jar MarkDuplicatesSpark --input=/home/hduser/data/example.unmarkedDups.bam -M=out_MarkDuplicatesMetrics.txt  --output=out_MarkDuplicates.bam`

Then I tried running this command that uses an input file in a HDFS store:

`spark-submit --class org.broadinstitute.hellbender.Main --master yarn --deploy-mode client /home/hadoop/spark.jar MarkDuplicatesSpark --input=hdfs://localhost:59000/data/example.unmarkedDups.bam -M=out_MarkDuplicatesMetrics.txt  --output=out_MarkDuplicates.bam`

And it froze on:

`scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) in 135 ms on localhost (1/2)`

Then I enabled logging level `ALL` in Spark and ran it again. This I've noticed the following message repeating every minute:

`TRACE HeartbeatReceiver: Checking for hosts with no recent heartbeats in HeartbeatReceiver`

I'd never stop and I had to kill the process.

What I have to do to fix this problem?